# Increase stack_size in iOS test bundle

Tags: ios, nsthread, stack-size

I'm trying to run unit tests, using XCTest, and  I need to increase stack_size to 2MB. 
When linking an executable, using -Wl,-stack_size option, I can change it. First question, I'm not sure if this option applies to all threads, or only the main thread?

The problem is that if I try to apply this setting to the test project, I have a link error saying that this option is only for executable.

Is there a way to do this? 
If not, I'll have to go with NSThread and increase stack_size? But I'm not sure how I could create a thread that will run all my tests ?

Thanks for your help.